# Accessing folder from main directory in subdomain

Tags: html, directory

So I have folder var/www/html/cms.leaguenotes and var/www/html/leaguenotes and I want to access files like css and stuff from cms.leaguenotes that are in the leaguenotes folder I've tried doing ../leaguenotes/css/somethingsomething but I get an error

for example

> http://cms.leaguenotes.com/leaguenotes/js/jquery.min.js Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Could you Share the domain name

Comment: you could probably access it at cms.leaguenotes.com

Comment: I think error in folder path, please try with actual path ie var/www/leagunotes/css/stye.css

Comment: http://leaguenotes.com/js/jquery.min.js

Comment: Use this it will resolve your issue

Comment: I've tried that it doesn't work

Comment: Are these two virtual sites? Or is it one site running both with URL Rewrite?

Comment: @Twisty Two virtual sites I've tried absolute destinations like /var/www/leagunotes/css/style.css with no success

Comment: Absolute destinations I do not think will work since the browser will not be able to make a GET of that path. This is why @kannan suggested using the FQDN path, which should work. When you said it did not work, what errors appeared in your Console?

Comment: @Twisty <script src="leaguenotes.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script> not found you can check it out at cms.leaguenotes.com

Comment: you have to add `http://` at the beginning of your address, otherwise the browser thinks you are referencing for a file named: _leaguenotes.com_, so the correct code will be like this: `<script src="http://www.leaguenotes.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I also removed `php` tag since the question is not related to `php` at all...

Comment: @EhsanT http://www.leaguenotes.com/css/general.css net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED that's what i get with your code you can check it at cms.leaguenotes.com

Comment: This suggests your local DNS is unaware of the domain name. I would fix this in the HOST file. Such that leaguenotes.com resolved to 127.0.0.1 or the local IP of the Apache server.

Comment: Looking at the page, `<script src="/var/www/html/leaguenotes/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>` is not correct. The others are working properly, at least from my external connection.

Comment: I think your problem is something else, like a `.htaccess` file or something similar. cause regardless of what is your `url`, you always face a _coming soon_ page under the `http://www.leaguenotes.com` domain. that's why your request for `css` or `js` files will not return the content of those files but will return the content of this _coming soon_ page. check to see if you have any `.htaccess` file in the root of your domain and if so, please change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at your page, you need to use complete URL paths:

```
<head>
        <script src="http://www.leaguenotes.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.leaguenotes.com/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="http://www.leaguenotes.com/css/general.css">
        <title>CMS administration
        </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Viewing it locally, Apache should resolve it properly, yet you may need to override this with the `host` file. Add:

```
127.0.0.1    www.leaguenotes.com
127.0.0.1    leaguenotes.com
```

This can help ensure that it's resolving the domain name properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with actual URL

http://www.leaguenotes.com/js/jquery.min.js

I hope it may help to resolve your problem

Comment: It does but in the long run it doesn't really help me because I would have to change that everytime I'm moving files from local server to my deployment